# Vocal tuning (metering, not autotuning)

Tags: tuning, voice, meter

I've tried using the built-in instrument tuner from [Apple Logic Pro](http://www.apple.com/logicpro/) to check if I'm on tune when singing, but a lot of the time, it takes a few seconds to react to whatever's happening (even if playback, not live) and even when it does, I'd like to have a better monitor than making the red turn blue to know I'm hitting the right note. I almost never say on a blue, it's all over the place, as far as 50 cents, even when it sounds like the right note compared to the piano. I know I'm not THAT pitchy/have a teacher who says I'm pretty much on pitch. I'd like to see frequencies and such, and a better response. Does anyone know of a plugin like that for Mac?

I try searching on Google, but it gets confused and thinks I'm talking about autotuning.

Comment: Shameless plug follows: Sing-inTuna, an iPhone app I wrote to help me practice singing. Shows several different tuning markers that respond in under 100 milliseconds with an accuracy of a maybe few cents.  It's in the iOS App Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tuner in Logic is designed for tuning instruments, so it takes a moving average. The properties you need for monitoring your singing - a fast response, and accuracy when you're quickly changing pitch, simply weren't design goals for that tool.

For the same reasons, a typical tuner from a music shop, probably won't achieve what you want. A basic guitar tuner requires that you play a single note firmly, on its own, to get an accurate reading.

There is software, and there are pieces of hardware, designed to give visual feedback on vocal pitch. Googling "vocal pitch meter" gave me the [Roland VT-12 Vocal Trainer](http://www.rolandconnect.com/product_2012-09.php?p=vt-12) (hardware), [PitchPerfector](http://onpitchsinging.com/index-extra.html) (Windows software) and [Voice Tutor](http://voicetutorapp.com) (iPhone and Android software). I cannot personally vouch for any of those, but they seem to support the purpose you have in mind. In addition to displaying your sung pitch visually, each of them also includes exercises targeted at improving your overall singing ability.

Comment: From what I can see from their website and video demo, Voice Tutor for iPhone and Android does not have anything to do with intonation or measuring pitch.

Comment: @WheatWilliams Is there not a pitch meter at the bottom of the last screenshot on the link for that software?

Comment: I do not know what that is, because I have not tried the program.

Comment: Hey thanks, I know it's late, but checked out the Vocal Trainer. Seems cool. Wondered about the price. OUCH, $200. The others sound good. Also I found a nag-ware app for mac called Vocal Lab by rustykat that does a pretty nice job of both pitch and frequency on a chart. It's free to try, but 15 to buy, and believe me it will let you know, every 2 mins or so. That's the only catch. I don't have money but when I do I'll be tossing money their way. Thanks, I never knew tuners worked differently. Neither did the Logic forum apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "Tuner" or "from Logic" is, but I can tell you that all tuners have some filtering, aka integration, built in.  If they didn't the meter would be oscillating all the time due to minor background noise, natural variation in pitch input, etc.
It may be that the tuner you're using has a very long filter, and thus takes longer than you would like to settle.  I do know that a couple Windows-based tuners have an option to change this filter time; perhaps yours does as well.

All in all,  why not spend a few bucks and get a standalone tuner such as the KorgCA40 or OT120 (or similar tuners from Seiko or others)?

Edit - since the other answer is close to mine anyway,  consider getting some freeware app which displays an FFT.  There are tons of those-heck, I found a few for Android :-) .   A typical FFT app updates several times a second, so you can see any waver in your pitch pretty easily.

Comment: Carl Witthoft, the questioner is referring to the built-in instrument tuner in the Apple Logic Pro digital audio workstation package, the chief competitor to Avid Pro Tools. http://www.apple.com/logicpro/